# WordPress posting admin throws strict mode error on one server

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, concatenation, bundling-and-minification

I have 3 development environments for my WordPress project:

- Local environment
- Staging server
- Production server

I am only getting the error on the production server, which is, unfortunately, the most important place for it to work.

[image]
[image]

What could be causing this error? It is generated by the script loader in /wp-admin/load-scripts.php and it only throws the error when using the posting editor pages in the WP admin.

The problem only happens on one of three servers and it causes many JS related functions on those pages to fail, like modifying the post's publication date or adding tags.

Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated.

---

**EDIT**

Hrmm.. after doing some digging I am wondering if it may have to do with some PHP ini settings which are used for concatenation and minification of the JS files. Disabling my plugins did nothing.

I am looking at this part of the WP core script loader (/wp-includes/script-loader.php):

```
/**
 * Determine the concatenation and compression settings for scripts and styles.
 *
 * @since 2.8.0
 *
 * @global bool $concatenate_scripts
 * @global bool $compress_scripts
 * @global bool $compress_css
 */
 function script_concat_settings() {
     global $concatenate_scripts, $compress_scripts, $compress_css;

     $compressed_output = ( ini_get('zlib.output_compression') || 'ob_gzhandler' == ini_get('output_handler') );

    if ( ! isset($concatenate_scripts) ) {
        $concatenate_scripts = defined('CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS') ? CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS : true;
        if ( ( ! is_admin() && ! did_action( 'login_init' ) ) || ( defined('SCRIPT_DEBUG') && SCRIPT_DEBUG ) )
            $concatenate_scripts = false;
    }

    if ( ! isset($compress_scripts) ) {
        $compress_scripts = defined('COMPRESS_SCRIPTS') ? COMPRESS_SCRIPTS : true;
        if ( $compress_scripts && ( ! get_site_option('can_compress_scripts') || $compressed_output ) )
            $compress_scripts = false;
    }

    if ( ! isset($compress_css) ) {
        $compress_css = defined('COMPRESS_CSS') ? COMPRESS_CSS : true;
        if ( $compress_css && ( ! get_site_option('can_compress_scripts') || $compressed_output ) )
           $compress_css = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: My edit seems to have led me in the right direction. After disabling concatenation I can use the post editor correctly but getting a different error now `unexpected end of output`. Going to have to take a look into `php.ini` for zlib compression settings

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty convinced that the error is coming from the javascript strict mode which is enabled probably in your production environment. If in your second screenshot "g" is an object, than you should know that you cannot use `delete g`. In strict mode you can only delete editable object properties.

For reference see this page (search delete on the page)  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode

Comment: Javascript strict mode is also enabled in my local and staging environments

Comment: `'use strict'` statements are coming from the files it loads so there is no differences; that said, there are extra plugin configurations on the production server for captchas and it is possibly coming from there. For instance, if these files aren't being loaded on staging.

Comment: You might want to try and check if those extra plugins / configurations are the culprits. Also you might want to check if the script you are loading for this function is up to date or if the configurations are omitting on purpose "use strict" on development. Removing "use strict" might probably resolve your problem, however it's a layer of constraint which is intended to protect the code.

Comment: Ya, I agree. I don't want to have to disable strict mode, especially one coming from 3rd party code.

Comment: Seems still to happen even after disabling all plugins. I'm a bit stumped on this one.